# real time mouse tracking via the external js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, real-time

I have a simple example of real-time mouse movement using node.js and socket.io.

When I want to include it on any html site I have to connect to node.js server:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  socket.emit('movement', {
    'id': socket.id,
    ..
  });
});

// more code later..
```

I would like to offer other people o track their websites. Most apps are requiring to insert code like this(of course async - not this simple way):

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/connect.js"></script>
```

That's the way I would like to handle it either. Should I just copy and paste content of socket.io.js + my code into connect.js?

Is it a good approach or what's the better way to connect random website to my node.js server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a script to allow web clients to connect to your web socket server.

You can create one file that:

- Load some libraries like jQuery and/or socket.io (other websites may not have those loaded)
- Then execute your application logic

So you need to load libraries before your application logic.

Like this:

```
// embedded-script.js

// You can use this simple function to load the libraries you need
function loadScripts(scripts, complete) {
    var loadScript = function( src ) {
        var xmlhttp, next;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            try {
                 xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(e) {
                return;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
                next = scripts.shift();
                if ( next ) {
                    loadScript(next);
                } else if ( typeof complete == 'function' ) {
                    complete();
                }
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", src , true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    };
    loadScript( scripts.shift() );
}

// load the libraries you need
loadScripts([
  "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js", // assuming you need jQuery
  "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.5.0/socket.io.min.js"
], function() {
   // libraries loaded.
   // your application logic here
});
```

and then give websites owners this embed code:

```
<script src="http://your-domain.com/embedded-script.js"></script>
```

---

Some considerations:

- Distribute your script within a CDN
- If your application logic involves a large number of files, maybe you need a module loader for requiring your scripts. eg. [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/).
- I suggest you to not emit socket messages on mousemove! It will be an overkill for your server. You should change your mouse tracking logic with something less expensive, for example by wrapping your emit with [a throttle or a debouncer](https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls) or by just track mouse clicks.